# Python: import module that also imports another module

Tags: python-2.7

I had a python file with many methods (def name()). Inside this method other were imported such as matplotlib ( import matplotlib as plt). Now I have splited my file into two so one file contains the methods and the other only have calls to this methods. The problem is that now the modules that were imported in the file that contains the methods are not recognised: NameError: global name 'plt' is not defined

Comment: Put the statement `import matplotlib as plt` in every file that contains references to the symbol `plt` and remove that statement from files that no longer reference `plt`.  Restart python to ensure the modules are loaded in their updated state.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I got the same error. It seems that it works if I write "import matplotlib as plt" inside the method that uses it o if I write the same outside the method and I add the line "global plt". So I just import inside the file that contains all the methods